# Read more option in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using [this](https://github.com/andoulla/Read-More-Directive) directive to implement a read-more in my ionic app.
My HTML looks like this:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item class="item item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="sh in schedule_hosts" type="item-text-wrap">
        <img ng-src={{sh.imageURL}}>
        <h2>{{sh.firstName}} {{sh.lastName}}</h2>
        <p>{{sh.profession.EN}}</p>
        <p read-more ng-model="content" words="true" length="5"></p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

And in my controller:

```
$scope.content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi commodo, ipsum sed pharetra gravida, orci magna rhoncus neque, id pulvinar odio lorem non turpis. Nullam sit amet enim. Suspendisse id velit vitae ligula volutpat condimentum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper, lectus nunc ullamcorper orci, fermentum bibendum enim nibh eget ipsum. Donec porttitor ligula eu dolor. Maecenas vitae nulla consequat libero cursus venenatis. Nam magna enim, accumsan eu, blandit sed, blandit a, eros." +
            "Quisque facilisis erat a dui. Nam malesuada ornare dolor. Cras gravida, diam sit amet rhoncus ornare, erat elit consectetuer erat, id egestas pede nibh eget odio. Proin tincidunt, velit vel porta elementum, magna diam molestie sapien, non aliquet massa pede eu diam. Aliquam iaculis. Fusce et ipsum et nulla tristique facilisis. Donec eget sem sit amet ligula viverra gravida. Etiam vehicula urna vel turpis. Suspendisse sagittis ante a urna. Morbi a est quis orci consequat rutrum. Nullam egestas feugiat felis. Integer adipiscing semper ligula. Nunc molestie, nisl sit amet cursus convallis, sapien lectus pretium metus, vitae pretium enim wisi id lectus." +
            "Proin at eros non eros adipiscing mollis. Donec semper turpis sed diam. Sed consequat ligula nec tortor. Integer eget sem. Ut vitae enim eu est vehicula gravida. Morbi ipsum ipsum, porta nec, tempor id, auctor vitae, purus. Pellentesque neque. Nulla luctus erat vitae libero. Integer nec enim. Phasellus aliquam enim et tortor. Quisque aliquet, quam elementum condimentum feugiat, tellus odio consectetuer wisi, vel nonummy sem neque in elit. Curabitur eleifend wisi iaculis ipsum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In non velit non ligula laoreet ultrices. Praesent ultricies facilisis nisl. Vivamus luctus elit sit amet mi.";
```

This works fine, but as you can see, the content is now the same for every item.
I looking for a way to create a read more functionality that allows me to add the text in HTML, like this:

```
<p read-more ng-model="content" words="true" length="5">{{sh.content}}</p>
```

I'm very (very) new to Angularjs and Ionic, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Replace `ng-model="content"` with your model i.e `ng-model="sh.content"`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This shows the correct text, but I'm getting this error in the console: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null` . Also, if the string is empty (which can be the case), it breaks everything...

Comment: Update: everything seems to work fine as long as all the `sh.content` are strings. The moment `sh.content` is `null`, I get the error mentioned above.

Comment: Adding `ng-if="sh.content"`fixed the issue above.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you looking for directives. The directive is a feature same as web components.

You issue may be solved like that.

**read-more-content.html**

```
<p ng-if="content" read-more ng-model="content" words="true" length="length">{{content}}</p>
```

**read.more.content.js**

```
angular.module('App')
    .directive('readMoreContent', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                content: '=',
                length: '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/components/_read-more.html'
        };
    });
```

And usage can be similar like that

```
<read-more-content content="content" length="5"></read-more-content>
```

My personal advice split your own code in angular on small components/directives. That allow you avoid lot's of headacke in nearest refactoring. I'm looking forward doing something similar to http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/atomic-web-design/ but in angular.